# Necessary condition for rows of a matrix to be mutually orthogonal

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, orthogonality, orthogonal-matrices

Given a matrix $A$ of order $M \times N$, the necessary condition for all rows to be mutually orthogonal is $N \ge M$. How do I prove it?

Comment: Welcome to math SE. People here like to see the efforts you made. Please edit your post ot include some of your thoughts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**HINT**

To be mutually orthogonal the rows must be linearly independent.